# Що означає "Абищиця"?

Tags: значення-слів

У словнику Грiнченка зустрічається такий вираз: “Це така абищиця, що не варт і казати…”.Що означає слово "Абищиця"? я так розумiю, що це,мабуть, пуста обiцянка. Можливо, помиляюсь. Пiдскажiть, будь ласка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Словнику Української Мови Online](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=28&page=1)  надано таке тлумачення слова *абищиця*:

> **АБИ́ЩИЦЯ**, і, ж., розм. Річ або справа, що не має ніякої цінності чи значення; дрібниця, дурниця.

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html) наводить такий переклад і синонімічний ряд:

> • **плёвое дело** (разг.) – дурниця, *абищиця*, пусте, пустячина, казна-що.

Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов):

> **Ко́е-что́** – де́що (де́чого, де́чому и т. д.), де́не́що (р. де́нечого),
>   аби́-що (р. аби́-чого), де́щиця, *аби́щиця* (-ці), що(сь).
>
> **Мелочь**
>
> 6) (пустяк) дрібни́ця, дрібни́чка, дрі́б’язок, *аби́щиця*, марни́ця,
>   (жалкий) нікче́мниця, мізе́рія, (малость) ма́лість (-лости).

Comment: Дякую за вiдповiдь)

Answer (score -1):

Питання було щодо значення слова, але хотів би додати трохи про його етимологію. Слово "Абищиця" утворилося злиттям "Аби" і "Що". Є ще кілька слів утворених подібним чином. "Коби" - скорочення/злиття "Коли б" (застаріле?); "Нісенітниця" - "Ні се ні те" (Може й жарт, але новотвір нітенісниця матиме такий же зміст). Ще є російська мовна конструкція, яка якимось чином навіть утвердилася в українській юриспруденції - "Нікчемний" - "Ни к чему"(рос.)